# Support With Sharing AppleScriptObjC Variable To Label Object

Tags: xcode, applescript, applescript-objc

```
   script AppDelegate  

        property theWindow : missing value
        property displayLabel : missing value

            on applicationWillFinishLaunching:aNotification

                    display dialog "Are you ready?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button "Yes"

            end applicationWillFinishLaunching:

            if result = {button returned:"No"} then

                display alert "That's a shame."

                tell application "This Application"
                    quit
                end tell

            else if result = {button returned:"Yes"} then

                set testVariable to "this is a test"

            end if

    end script
```

So, this is an example of an app I'm working on in AppleScriptObjC.  I've taken a lot out and replaced things with different strings, but this is the basic layout.

How can I get the value of 'testVariable' into the 'displayLabel' property, which is linked to a label in the interface builder?  The label is empty initially, but I want the value of 'testVariable' to populate it once the script has been run.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is pretty similar to the ObjC syntax

ObjC

```
displayLabel.stringValue = testVariable;
```

AppleScriptObjC

```
set displayLabel's stringValue to testVariable
```

Comment: Thanks Vadian! That was a big help.

Comment: I'd like to ask a follow up question if that's ok vadian; in the example code I've shown, the main app window is visible and blank behind the dialog box as soon as you open the app. Is there a way to hide this main app window, until the appropriate dialog box has been selected and the label has been populated?  Thanks!

Comment: hide the window in Interface Builder (deselect "Visible At Launch") and show the window programmatically with the method `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` of `NSWindow`